# Using css translate -50% to centre div doesn't apply to Firefox saved details pop-up

Tags: css, firefox, transform

I've used the following css to centre a div on screen (no fixed width or height so can't use defined pixel width and height and negative margins).

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I've just realised that when you have saved your details for a form in Firefox, and then try to fill in the form within my div, the pop-up Firefox creates that contains your saved details is ignoring the transform, and appearing in the location on screen where the entire div would be if transform: translate wasn't applied.

It's difficult to give an example of this because it requires you to have saved your login details to a site, but if you go to a site where you have saved details, and move the container using transform: translate, you'll see the effect.

Is there a way of forcing Firefox's pop-up to take on the transform? Or will I need to find a different way of centring my div onscreen?

Comment: can you share page html also or may be link if possible. this is n't enough to understand issue. For now maybe `-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` will help :)

Comment: I've already tried that :). I can't share the link, but try editing in inspect element on any site where you have saved your login details in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of browser support do you need? you can solve this with flexbox!

```
body (or container-div) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Transform takes its percentage calculation from the element itself though, and margin refers to the container element, so that doesn't centre it. If there's no way round it I might need to use javascript to calculate the negative margins required. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're totally right, my bad. I edited the answer to give you another alternative.

Comment: I do need it to be backwards-compatible, but will add something else to make it degrade for IE9 and below. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your CSS should be right, but the position should be fixed on your parent div

w3schools: [position: absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

```
.parent{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to center div on a page. It is a more elegant approach.

```
.center{
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
height:some-height;
width:some-width;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a defined width and height as there are a few divs using the same styling which are different sizes, so can't use this method.

Comment: It will be useful if you show jsfiddle demo. so that i can check it locally.